# merge django's auth_user with existing user table

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

Currently I have a legacy app which refers to a `user` table with all the custom fields. Since there is a good amount of legacy code referring to that table I cannot simple rename that table as `auth_user`. So the thing I'm trying to do is somehow merge (i don't know that its the right term) `auth_user` and `user`.

Below is `user` table:

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id           | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name              | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address           | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phone_no          | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city              | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state             | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pin_no            | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type              | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email             | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password          | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active         | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| role              | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| creation_date     | int(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| edit_date         | int(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| district          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip                | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| added_by          | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_phone_verified | binary(1)    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| remember_token    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| disclaimer_agreed | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| mobile_login      | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and django's `auth_user` table:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| password     | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_login   | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_superuser | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username     | varchar(150) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| first_name   | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name    | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(254) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_staff     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_joined  | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What I would want is a single table, that django will refer to in using `contrib.auth` related stuff and also at the same time does not deprecate my legacy code. maybe something like this:

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id           | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name              | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address           | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phone_no          | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city              | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state             | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pin_no            | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type              | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email             | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password          | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active         | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| role              | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| creation_date     | int(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| edit_date         | int(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| district          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip                | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| added_by          | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_phone_verified | binary(1)    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| remember_token    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| disclaimer_agreed | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| mobile_login      | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| last_login        | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_superuser      | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username          | varchar(150) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| first_name        | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name         | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_staff          | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active         | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_joined       | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

> The motive here is to take advantage of Django's builtin `authentication` and `permission` system but without breaking legacy code. I think there must be a solution for this as this is not the first time someone is porting some legacy application to django.

I would also like to mention this link [How to Extend Django User Model](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html), but I'm not sure which approach is the best to adopt or should I be doing something completely different

Comment: I don't understand why you want to merge them. Why not add a one-to-one relationship between them?

Comment: the `auth_user` table is not populated, while I have a lot of entries in the `user` table. Also doing a one-to-one relationship would mean i'll might have to use joins at some point, which might not go well with `restframework`'s existing serializers/viewsets

Comment: That still doesn't mean you need to merge them, it means you need to use your own custom model, which is well documented.

Comment: what if i inherit from `auth_user` as a proxy model, suggested here https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#proxy that solves a great deal of mess i guess

Comment: No there's no need for that at all. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django explicitly supports custom user models. Create a model for your existing table, make it inherit from AbstractBaseUser, and set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting to point to your new model.  See the [comprehensive docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: That's really helpful, but it clearly states that - `Don’t forget to point AUTH_USER_MODEL to it. Do this before creating any migrations or running manage.py migrate for the first time` - I am already beyond this step. If i change this now, what effect will it have? Should I just drop those tables create in the above step and then point `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to it and then rerun new migrations?

Comment: Yes, if you're still in development the best thing to do would be to drop the db, delete the migrations, then create them again.

Comment: what if I cannot drop the existing user table and re run the migrations ?

Comment: The guidelines have changed since I originally wrote that, see the updated docs on [changing to a custom user model mid-project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project).

Answer (score 0):

We can read in more detail from a [Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313) how to migrate from a built-in User model to a custom User model.

Quoting from [Carsten Fuchs](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313#comment:18)

> **Assumptions**
>
> - Your project doesn't have a custom user model yet.
> - All existing users must be kept.
> - There are no pending migrations and all existing migrations are applied.
> - It is acceptable that all previous migrations are lost and can no longer be unapplied, even if you use version control to checkout old
>     commits that still have the migration files. This is the relevant
>     downside of this approach.
>
> **Preparations**
>
> - Make sure that any third party apps that refer to the Django User model only use the ​[generic referencing methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).
> - Make sure that your own reusable apps (apps that are intended to be used by others) use the generic reference methods.
> - I suggest to not do the same with your project apps: The switch to a custom user model is only done once per project and never again. It
>     is easier (and in my opinion also clearer) to change `from
>     django.contrib.auth.models import User` to something else (as detailed
>     below) than replacing it with generic references that are not needed
>     in project code.
> - Make sure that you have a backup of your code and database!
>
> **Update the code**
>
> - You can create the new user model in any existing app or a newly created one. My preference is to create a new app:
>
>   ```
>   ./manage.py startapp Accounts
>   ```
>
> I chose the name "Accounts", but any other name works as well.
>
> - Aymeric: „Create a custom user model identical to `auth.User`, call it `User` (so many-to-many tables keep the same name) and set
>     `db_table='auth_user'` (so it uses the same table).“ In
>     `Accounts/models.py`:
>
>   ```
>   from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
>   from django.db import models
>
>
>   class User(AbstractUser):
>   class Meta:
>           db_table = 'auth_user'
>   ```
> - In `settings.py`, add the app to `INSTALLED_APPS` and update the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting:
>
>   ```
>   INSTALLED_APPS = (
>       # ...
>       'Accounts',
>   )
>
>   AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Accounts.User'
>   ```
> - In your project code, replace all imports of the Django user model:
>
>   ```
>   from django.contrib.auth.models import User with the new, custom one:
>   ```
>
>   from Accounts.models import User
> - Delete all old migrations. (Beforehand, see if [comment 14](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313#comment:14) is relevant to you!) For example, in the project root:
>
>   ```
>   find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
>   find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc" -delete
>   ```
> - Create new migrations from scratch:
>
>   ```
>   ./manage.py makemigrations
>   ```
> - Make any changes to your admin.py files as required. (I cannot give any solid information here, but this is not crucial for the result and
>     so the details can still be reviewed later.)
> - Make sure that your testsuite completes successfully! (A fresh test database must be used, it cannot be kept from previous runs.)
> - At this point, the changes to the code are complete. This is a good time for a commit.
>
> Note that we're done – except that the new migration files mismatch
>   the contents of the `django_migrations` table.
>
> (It may even be possible to serve your project at this point: It's
>   easy to back off before the database is actually changed. *Only* do
>   this if you understand that you cannot even touch the migrations
>   system as long as the steps below are not completed!)
>
> **Update the database**
>
> - Truncate the django_migrations table. MySQL 8 example:
>
>   ```
>     TRUNCATE TABLE django_migrations;
>   ```
>
> This is possibly different for other databases or verions of MySQL <
>   8.
>
> - Fake-apply the new set of migrations
>         ./manage.py migrate --fake
> - Check the ContentTypes as described at [comment 12](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313#comment:12)
>
> **Conclusion**
>
> - The upgrade to the custom user model is now complete. You can make changes to this model and generate and apply migrations for it as with
>     any other models.
> - As a first step, you may wish to unset `db_table` and generate and apply the resulting migrations.
> - In my opinion, the startproject management command should anticipate the introduction of a custom user model.